# WPF Grid is not stretching vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, grid

I've the following `Grid` in the main window:

```
<Grid Name="gridMain" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
</Grid>
```

I'm adding a `UserControl` dynamically in the grid. The main window only has this grid. I want the grid to be stretched both horizontally and vertically and should fill up entire window. The grid is stretching horizontally but **doesn't stretch vertically**. Any idea why? What do I need to do to make the grid stretch vertically?

EDIT

Here is the complete XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="Sensitech.TurboValidator.UserControls.ConveyorBelt"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ConveyorBelt" Height="329" Width="714" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
    <Grid Name="gridMain" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Background="Cyan">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I just put your `Xaml` into Wpf app and gave it a background color. It worked with no problems. Is the **gridMain** the root `Xaml` object?

Comment: @MarkHall: no, it's not the root object. Please check my edit.

Comment: As usual WPF makes things awkward. WTF is wrong with anchors, anchors work. +1 for the background idea, might help me to find which of the 27 controls I have to set VerticalAlignment="Stretch" on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting row height to *

```
<Grid Name="gridMain" >    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Similarly define ColumnDefinition and set Width to *

Also make sure grid is the one not stretching not the user control. You can easily do that by assigning some background color to Grid.

Comment: thanks for the background color idea. i found that the grid is actually stretching. the user control isn't. what property will help stretch the user control?

Comment: i fixed it. it was the height of the usercontrol. thanks again for back color idea.

Comment: Well if main control in User Control is Grid then you can do as I have suggested. Similarly if you have stack panel try to set vertical allignment to stretch. It depends on controls you have in user control

Answer (score 0):

There is a SizeChanged event in xaml
e.g. SizeChanged="WindowSizeChanged"
Use this to resize your controls to the size you want based on the window size.

```
    private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid1.Height = this.ActualHeight - 40;
    }
```

"Would you jump from a plane if you were told your parachute was packed by the xaml designers?"

Answer (score 0):

Use this grid class in window root. I am giving this answer since none of their answers above helped me.

```
public class SpaceFiller : Grid
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var size = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
        return new Size(size.Width, availableSize.Height);
    }
}
```