# WPF Grid not stretching with window

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

I'm dynamically painting to my canvas which is inside of my WPF grid but neither the canvas or the grid is stretching appropriately. Here is some of my code....

```
    <Window x:Class="WPFNimGame.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Game of Nim" Height="auto" Width="auto"  PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown_1" Name="Window">
<Grid Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="33"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <!--<Grid.Background>--> 
        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource=".\Properties\black-diamond-plate.bmp" -->
        <!-- </Grid.Background>-->
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="{Binding ElementName=Window,Path=Width}" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0" >
            <MenuItem Name="File" Header="File" Click="File_Click_1">
                <MenuItem Name="NewGame" Header="New Game" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
    <Canvas  Name="paintCanvas"  Width="{Binding ElementName=Grid,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=Grid,Path=ActualHeight}" MouseLeftButtonDown="paintCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="10" ></Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You set the height of row 1 in the RowDefinition  but for the content of row 1 you set the height to grid height.  In math they call that over defined.

Comment: Take out all references to Vertical/Horizontal Alignment, height, and width. If you want your object to always be in a certain row/column, all you need is to specify the column, row, column span, and row span. To expand your grid, put a * next to the definitions (ex. 33* or just *). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answ[Try to set row height *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641456/wpf-grid-is-not-stretching-vertically)

```
<Grid Name="gridMain" > 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinition>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Width or Height a `Grid` are equal to "NaN", they will be determined based on the Size of its `Children`. The problem is that you have set the Size of the `Children` to be the same as the Size of the Grid. This will not work and the result will always be 0.

The size of the Children is determined based on their contents or children. if you want them to have a definite size, then set Height and Width to be equal to a specific double.